# Are 8 cells of 1.2 V enough for my Quadruped(spider)?

Tags: mobile-robot, battery, power, legged

i have a sprawling type quadruped spider robot. I have 4 Sg90 and 8 mg996r servos used for the legs. I am using a Arduino Mega and I wanted to know if I would be able to power this with the batteries that I have... Currently I have 8 cells of 1.2 V 2600mah Recyko Nimh batteries. I plan to put 4 cells in one battery holder and 4 in another and solder them together which would provide about 9.6 V. The Mg996r datasheet needs around 300-800 mA of current and S90 around 100- 300 mA of current. Should be around 2-9 A of current that my circuit needs. Would my battery be enough to provide this kind of power? If not is there a workaround? Lipo or any other type of battery is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

If your batteries are GP260AAHC then [the datasheet](https://www.batterystation.co.uk/content/datasheets_MSDS/GP/GP%20Recyko%20plus%20%20AA%202600mAh%20Battery%20Product%20Data%20Sheet.pdf) has 7800mA as the upper recommended discharge current, so you're probably ok as long as you don't move everything at once.

Workaround might be to find some other AA batteries with a higher recommended discharge current in their datasheet.

Comment: OP could also double the battery pack; putting a second pack in parallel would halve the current draw to each pack, such that a 9 amp total output would be ~4.5 amps from each pack, which is under the 7.8 amp limit you're quoting.

Comment: @Chuck do you mean i buy 8 more cells and put them in parallel? Or just put the 4 each in parallel? Because if i put the 8 i have in parallel then the supply voltage will not be enough

Comment: @AbhinavRao Add them in parallel to the current 8 cells. But that means you have doubled the weight, and I suspect there are slightly higher discharge cells available which are not twice the weight. Another possibly lighter option is to add a capacitor if you're only pulling 9A briefly, but then if you're only pulling 9A briefly you're under the 7.8A continuously over 20 minutes shown in the datasheet.

Comment: @AbhinavRao - I'm suggesting doubling the battery pack (8 more cells if you have today) and putting them in *parallel,* not *series.* This would keep the voltage the same.